# prevent a regex to modify all a string

Tags: php, regex

Currently, l'm programming a small application and the future users of it will be able to write messages which will be parsed by a function (some regex).

For example, when the user write

```
":)"
```

it's transformed into

```
<img src="link" alt="link" />
```

And in the same way, when he write

```
[code]my code :)[/code]
```

it's transformed into

```
<pre>my code <img src="link" alt="link" /></pre>
```

here is an example :

http://www.legeekcafe.com/upload/img/4298Capture.PNG

It's a big problem as you can see. So **how can I prevent the regex to parse the smilies for example inside my code blocks ?**

Thanks you

Comment: The solution is to not use regexes for this.  You need a more sophisticated parser.

Comment: Do you know a more sophisticated parser that i could use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) and put the code block detection in a subpattern and everything that appears before the code block subpattern into a another subpattern.
Then replace inside of the callback just the first subpattern (so not the code block) with your smiley regex.

Comment: So :) 

 - I replace all ma [code][/code] by [code id=X] and i save my code content in an array  
 - I parse my smilies  
 - I replace [code id=X] by the original content  
 - I parse my [code[/code]  

Thanks you :)